# jquery toggle click exclude children links

Tags: jquery, hyperlink, toggle, stoppropagation

I am trying to pop up a box when a div or any of its first level children are clicked, excluding one A tag that is in a child div.

I am simply switching classes to show/hide the div which works great. However, when the link is clicked the box still pops up which I dont want. I have looked at using target and stoppropagation but I cannot get it to work with my code.

**jQuery:**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery(".video_odd").toggle(function()
    {
    jQuery(this).children(".video_desc_box").attr('class', 'video_desc_box_open');
    },
    function(){
    jQuery(this).children(".video_desc_box_open").attr('class', 'video_desc_box');
    });
});
```

**Quick HTML overview**: video_odd is the class that when it is clicked it will cause its child div video_desc_box to switch its class to video_desc_box_open which changes display to inline instead of none.

I just don't understand how to use toggle to get this script to not run when a link is clicked which is a div inside video_odd.

I want it to change classes when any other childen is clicked, just not the 2nd level child link.

Thanks for the help!

**EDIT:** I think I am getting closer:

```
jQuery(".video_odd").toggle(function(e)
{
if (e.target == jQuery(this).children(".video_list_title")) { return; }
jQuery(this).children(".video_desc_box").attr('class', 'video_desc_box_open');
},
function(){
jQuery(this).children(".video_desc_box_open").attr('class', 'video_desc_box');
});
```

However

```
(e.target == jQuery(this).children(".video_list_title"))
```

Is not registering. How can I have it exclude the div video_list_title all together (not just the link?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

e.target is not a jQuery.

$(e.target).hasClass("video_list_title")

Is a lot closer!

Comment: I’m glad you asked on the jQuery forum as well. I don’t often check here. I need the points here!